# How to get Mew?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I saw someone with a Mew while I was trading. When I looked it up on GTS no Mew were there.
Any easy no hacking way to get one? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Mew is an event-only Legendary, so it can't be traded on GTS. And it can't be found in Pokemon ORAS neither.
The only way to get it is trade with random Passersby or friends.